# How to call a method of a class when it is in a list

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a very basic version of the old Asteroids game in javaFX to get back into programming. When generating asteroids and bullets (which are objects from classes) i keep them in a List. I am trying to get these asteroids to move on the screen, but i can't seem to find how to call a method from the object, only for the last object in the list. If i use list.forEach(object::method) i can get the asteroids moving, but each time the forEach method gets called it changes the velocity of all objects, which certainly isn't desirable. I would like to call the velocity method (floatSpeed) only for the last item in the list when it is generated. What could be my possible options here?

So I've tried making my own for loop to cycle through the objects and get those moving that have a Point2D velocity of x:0 y:0 with an IF statement, but this doesn't work because it never gets a true from the if statement.
The getVelocity method simply returns the current velocity of an object in Point2D format.

```
for (GameObject Asteroid : asteroids){
            if(Asteroid.getVelocity() == new Point2D(0,0)){
                Asteroid.floatSpeed();
                System.out.println("asteroid moving");
            }
```

This is what I've got so far to get the asteroids moving, but they update velocity each time the forEach loop gets called.

```
private List<GameObject> bullets = new ArrayList<>();
private List<GameObject> asteroids = new ArrayList<>();

private void addAsteroid(GameObject Asteroid, double x, double y){
        asteroids.add(Asteroid);
        addGameObject(Asteroid,x,y);
    }

    private void addGameObject(GameObject object, double x, double y){
        object.getView().setTranslateX(x);
        object.getView().setTranslateY(y);
        root.getChildren().add(object.getView());
    }

if (Math.random() < 0.01){
            addAsteroid(new Asteroid(), Math.random() * root.getPrefWidth(), Math.random() * root.getPrefHeight());
            asteroids.forEach(GameObject::floatSpeed);
        }
```

Comment: You want asteroids.get(asteroids.size() - 1) I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following line of code to call *floatSpeed()* on the last object of your *asteroids* array:

```
asteroids.get(asteroids.size()-1).floatSpeed();
```

*asteroids.get()* returns the object in specified index.
*asteroids.size()* returns the size of your list.
Indexing starts at 0, so you need to remove 1 from list size.
When you get the object from list, just call the method *floatSpeed()*.